# Example of Callback Hell

Tags: javascript, callback, timeout

I am trying to come up with a minimal example of what is known as callback hell in JavaScript (so this would be a bad code review I guess). This is what I have so far, and I would like it to also run without making external requests. I'm not sure if that's possible or if this example is hellish enough (do I need to introduce errors,arguments in the callbacks etc.). The point I am trying to make is that it is hard to tell when things happen.

I am aware of another hellish construct called the Pyramid of Doom, in my mind and from what I've read  that could be a different problem, i.e. while order is somehow clear, nesting makes it hard to troubleshoot,maintain and write.

```
function one() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('1. First thing calling Second thing');
    two();
  }, 2000);
};

function two() {
  console.log('2. Second thing');
}

function three() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('3. Third thing calling fourth thing');
    four();
  }, 1000);
}

function four() {
  console.log('4. Fourth thing');
}

one();
three();

// "3. Third thing calling fourth thing"
// "4. Fourth thing"
// "1. First thing calling Second thing"
// "2. Second thing"
```

Comment: In addition to being a "hypothetical" example, this question is off-topic for violating the "Do you want it to be good code?" rule. (See the [help/on-topic].)

Comment: @200_success sorry, It is not clear what that line means, what the heck is code golfing ? , anyways I did got my answer before your guys put it on hold and I think it is both useful and should be a minimal example rather than some production code. But I a don't have your fake points to defend myself, so I ll go play over there, have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your example is sufficient to demonstrate that `setTimeout` can result in weird interleavings. But if you asked *me* for an example of callback hell, I'd assume you wanted something like

```
function one() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('1. First thing setting up second thing');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('2. Second thing setting up third thing');
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('3. Third thing setting up fourth thing');
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('4. Fourth thing');
        }, 2000);
      }, 2000);
    }, 2000);
  }, 2000);
};
```

where the "hell" expresses itself in the form of a big triangle of whitespace along the left margin. You'd typically see this with API functions that take an "on success" callback and/or an "on failure" callback.

```
function compute_first_parameter(cb) { cb(42); } 
function compute_second_parameter(cb) { cb(10); }
function compute_sum(a, b, cb) { cb(a + b); }

function compute_a_result() {
    compute_first_parameter(function (x) {
        compute_second_parameter(function (y) {
            compute_sum(x, y, function(result) {
                console.log(result);  // 52
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Actually, http://callbackhell.com exists, and it has a good example right on the first page above the fold. So just go read that whole site. :)

Comment: I was just there !, So the issue I have is that most folks refer to your example as the Pyramid of Doom, which makes the point that nesting is not all that clear ( the order might be) , edited my question to clarify.